# Pre tags seem to ignore styles attribute (such as display:none)

Tags: javascript, html

## Overview:

I am trying to create a Javascript controlled box that displays content. This content will be code, highlighted by the "SyntaxHighlighter" extension. To highlight the code, the code must be enclosed in pre tags **with the brush class**.

## Problem:

Part of my Javascript attempts to hide this pre tag, so the page looks cleaner. However it can not change the .style.display attribute unless the pre tag is enclosed in a div tag.

## Code Snippets:

### Javascript:

```
    function decryptPaste() {
    try {
        post = sjcl.decrypt(
            $('#password3').val(),
            document.getElementById("paste_text").innerHTML()
        )
        document.getElementById("paste_text").innerHTML = post;
        document.getElementById("content-show").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("form-decrypt").style.display = "none"
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

### HTML (With some working PHP):

```
     <pre class="brush: text; toolbar: false;" style="display: none;" id="paste_text">
        <?php echo $c ?>
     </pre>
```

As always, any and all help appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the <pre> tag in a <div> for the styles:

```
 <div class="brush: text; toolbar: false;" style="display: none;">
    <pre id="paste_text">
      <?php echo $c ?>
    </pre>
 </div>
```

Comment: I believe that for the code to be highlighted, the code must be in pre tags. Unless I'm wrong, have you used SyntaxHighlighter before and can confirm this?

Comment: The code *is* in a pre tag in what I posted.  I'm not particularly familiar with SyntaxHighlighter, though.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I meant the class. I'll change my question.